# Is there any underlying reason behind this undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, gcc

I just tried this as an experiment to see what values are held in `d` at each call.
I used `gcc` on an x86-64 machine.

Is there any reason why the old value of d persists after the function returns? From what I understand the call stack frame is popped off once the function returns each time, correct?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(char ch){
  char d;
  printf("-- %c\n", d);
  d = ch;
}

int main(){
  fun('a');
  fun('b');
  fun('c');
  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
--
-- a
-- b
```

Comment: Given it's undefined, is there a reason why it *should not*? The stackframe is popped off, but nothing "clears" the previous value.

Comment: You just discovered stack necromancy. Now don't use it. People will be unhappy debugging it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return from a function, the memory that was part of the stack frame of the function typically won't be zero'ed out explicitly, as that would just take up unnecessary cycles.  So the memory won't be overwritten until it needs to be.

In your `main` function you call `fun` multiple times with no other statements in between.  That means that nothing in `main` touches the memory that was used by a prior invocation of `fun` before calling it again.  As a result, the stack frame of the second call happens to coincide with the stack frame of the first call.  And because uninitialized local variables don't get a default value, `d` takes on whatever value happens to be in that memory location, namely what `d` contained when the last call to the function returned.

If you added a call to another function such as `printf` in between each call to `fun`, then that other function call would write its own stack frame on top of the stack frame of the last call to `fun` so you would see different results in that case.